# Subset of natural numbers without certain limit

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

I'll lay out the whole problem first, then the part which I'm having trouble with.

Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the set of natural numbers, $A_{n} = \{1, 2, ..., n\}$, $\mathscr{A}$ the collection of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ such that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\#(A \cap A_{n})}{n}$$ exists.

Denote the function which maps $\mathscr{A}$ to the aforementioned limit as $\alpha$.

Prove that $\alpha$ is additive on the family $\mathscr{A}$ (for disjoint sets!), but that $\mathscr{A}$ is not closed for (finite) unions.

The additive part is easy, as $|(A \sqcup B) \cap A_{n}| = |A \cap A_{n}| + |B \cap A_{n}|$.

I can't think of an example of two (or more) sets which have this limit, but whose union does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be the set of all even natural numbers. Clearly $\alpha(A) = \frac{1}{2}$. For $B$, we take a set that switches between stretches of even numbers and stretches of odd numbers. For $k \in \mathbb{N}$, let $I_k = \{ n \in \mathbb{N} : k! \leqslant n < (k+1)!\}$, and define $B$ by

$$B \cap I_{2k} = A \cap I_{2k},\quad\text{and}\quad B \cap I_{2k+1} = I_{2k+1}\setminus A.$$

We also have $\alpha(B) = \frac{1}{2}$, which isn't hard to see. Then the density of $A \cup B$ fluctuates between $\frac{1}{2}$ and $1$,

$$\#\bigl((A\cup B) \cap A_{(2k+1)!}\bigr) \leqslant \frac{(2k+1)! + (2k)!}{2}$$

and

$$\#\bigl((A\cup B) \cap A_{(2k)!}\bigr) \geqslant (2k)! - (2k-1)!.$$

Comment: How did you find these estimates? I was able to prove the first inequality by noting that $\sum_{j=1}^{k} \#(B \cap I_{2j-1}) = \frac{(2k)!}{2}-2$ by telescoping the sum, and the second one by noting that $B$ will "add" (to the numbers $A$ has already "added" to the intersection) at least all of the odd numbers in $I_{2k-1}$, therefore at least $\frac{(2k)!-(2k-1)!}{2}$ numbers, which yields a slightly better estimate, $(2k)!-\frac{(2k-1)!}{2}$.

Comment: Oh, never mind, I see how you got the second one much more simply (and both of the limits are $1$, so the fact that my estimate is "better" doesn't matter, I just made the situation more complicated): $(A\cup B) \cap A_{(2k)!}$ will contain all of $I_{2k-1}$, so it'll have at least $(2k)! - (2k-1)!$ elements.

Comment: Yup, that's it. And $(A\cup B) \cap A_{(2k+1)!}$ contains at most everything below $(2k)!$ plus half of $I_{2k}$.

Comment: Another example: For $n\in N$ let $B_n=A_{2^{n+1}}$ \ $A_{2^n}.$.... Let  $A\cap B_n$ be the odd members of $B_n.$... Let $B\cap B_n=A\cap B_n$ when $n$ is even. Let $B\cap B_n$ be the even members of $B_n$ when  $n$ is odd.